# Java Jackson | How to serialize object specifying concrete interface

Tags: java, json, interface, jackson, polymorphism

Let's assume we have given Java interfaces:

```
public interface UserA {
    String getLogin();
    void setLogin(final String login);
}

public interface UserB {
    String getPassword();
    void setPassword(final String password);
}

public interface UserC {
    String getEmail();
    void setEmail(final String email);
}
```

And interface extending all of above:

```
public interface User extends UserA, UserB, UserC {
}
```

And class implementing User interface:

```
public class UserImpl implements User {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

Now, I'd like to serialize UserImpl object choosing one of 'small' interfaces (UserA, UserB, UserC) or the 'big' one (User).

Exmaples:

- expected result for UserA interface

  { "login" : "John" }
- expected result for UserB interface

  { password : "JohnSnow" }
- expected result for User interface

  { "login" : "John", password : "JohnSnow", "email" : "john@snow.com" }

Is there any method to get above result (changing JSON by switching interface) by passing one of object's interfaces to the Jackson mapper?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, but if you serialize `User` you get all three interfaces, regardless.  If you want only one you have to make separate types which implement only one interface each and serialize that.

Comment: Snippet included in @zappcity's answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ObjectMapper#writerFor` to choose which interface should be used when serializing. Here is a passing test that shows this functionality. If you are using an old version of Jackson that doesn't have `writerFor` then you can use `writerWithType`.

```
public interface A {
    String getStringA();
}

public interface B {
    String getStringB();
}

public class AB implements A, B {

    @Override
    public String getStringA() {
        return "value a";
    }

    @Override
    public String getStringB() {
        return "value b";
    }
}

@Test
public void t() throws JsonProcessingException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final String a = mapper.writerFor(A.class).writeValueAsString(new AB());
    assertThat(a).isEqualTo("{\"stringA\":\"value a\"}");

    final String b = mapper.writerFor(B.class).writeValueAsString(new AB());
    assertThat(b).isEqualTo("{\"stringB\":\"value b\"}");
}
```