# Casting an object to limit data serialized in Jackson serialization

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

Let's say I have the following classes:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(FullXResult::class, name = "X")
)
open class BaseResult {
 
    protected val mapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()    

    var x: String = "some shared text between all subclasses"
}

open class MinimalXResult: BaseResult() {
    var y: String = "some public text specific to X"
}

class FullXResult: MinimalXResult() {
    var z: String = "some private text specific to X"

    fun asMinimal(): MinimalXResult {
        return mapper.convertValue(this, MinimalXResult::class.java)
    }

}
```

I want to be able to deserialize a JSON into the FullResult, and before re-serialization, cast it to a MinimalResult to the caller such that for the example classes, the properties `x` and `y` are serialized but the property `z` is not. `@JsonIgnore` is not an option here because I also want to be able to return the full result under certain conditions.

When calling `asMinimal` function, I get the following error:

```
Could not resolve type id 'X' as a subtype of `MinimalXResult`: Class `FullXResult` not subtype of `MinimalXResult`
```

If this type of casting can be done without Jackson, that is fine too. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Jackson | How to serialize object specifying concrete interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527657/java-jackson-how-to-serialize-object-specifying-concrete-interface)

Comment: JsonViews might be another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279782/what-is-the-json-view-class-in-jackson-and-how-does-it-work